# Passing Start-Job parameters with -ArgumentList not working correctly

Tags: powershell

I have been playing with this for a bit, but not sure how to solve.

**The Scriptblock**

```
$removeScriptBlock1 = {
    param (

           [string]$ToDeleteFiles,

           [switch]$Recurse,

           [System.Object]$SubDirs) 

    Write-Host "ToDeleteFiles: $ToDeleteFiles"
    Write-Host "Recourse: $Recurse"
    Write-Host "SubDirs: $SubDirs"

    if($SubDirs) {

        write-host "In sub dir"
        return

    }

    if($Recurse){

        Write-Host "In Recurse"

    } else {

        Write-Host "Not Recurse"

    }
}
```

**Run #1**

```
$j = Start-Job $removeScriptBlock1 -ArgumentList "C:\Test",$True,('a')

Wait-Job $j

Receive-Job -job $j
```

**Output #1**

****Recurse** & **SubDirs** are wrong.**

```
ToDeleteFiles: C:\Test

Recurse: **False**

SubDirs: **True**

In sub dir
```

Comment: Change `[switch]$Recurse` for `[bool]$Recurse` then inside the scriptblock you can do `-Recurse:$Recurse`. See linked answer for more details / workarounds.

Comment: I guess you didnt like that the answer was about `Invoke-Command` (nonetheless those workarounds also apply here) instead of `Start-Job` so I added an additional one that has another workaround and focuses on `Start-Job`. ;)

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Comment: In short: `Start-Job`'s (as well as `Invoke-Command`'s) `-ArgumentList` parameter only allows passing _positional_ arguments, whereas `[switch]` parameters _cannot be bound positionally_.